# ¿Hay alguna manera de que en un array de mysql en php hacer una acción cada vez que el valor de una columna en específico cambie?

Tags: php, mysql

Si tengo una tabla donde una columna es 'tema', y quiero mostrar en un array de php los valores de cada entrada de la tabla, pero quiero que se diferencien automáticamente los divs en los que aparece cada uno de los temas.
Llevo esto, y me gustaría poder diferenciar las en diferentes filas de la tabla cada vez que cambia el valor de la columna tema de la base de datos. Y si es posible, cada vez que cambie poner el nombre del tema. Soy algo nuevo en el tema y no sé los fallos que podría tener el código. Esto es lo que llevo

```
<div class="row">
                  <div class="col-12">
                    <style>img{width:100%}
                        #videoplay button{background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 
 0.0);padding:0%;}
                        #videoplay img{transition:transform .2s}
                        #videoplay button:hover img{transform: 
    scale(1.1);}
                                                    @media screen and 
     (min-width: 650px) {#table.desktop{display:block} 
     #table.phone{display:none}}
                                                    @media screen and 
 (max-width: 650px) {#table.desktop{display:none} 
  #table.phone{display:block}}
                    </style>
                    <?php if(($_SESSION['user_id'])!=''){
                      $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM videos 
    WHERE asignatura='Biología'");

    echo '<table id="desktop">';
    $i = 1; //first, i set a counter
    while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    //counter is zero then we are start new row
     if ($i==0){
    echo '<tr>';
       }
     //here we creating normal cells <td></td>
      $name = $fetch['nombre'];
        $image_location = $fetch['thumbnail'];
        echo '<td>
  <form action="video_player.php" id="videoplay">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" 
   value="'.urlencode(base64_encode($fetch['id'])).'">
  <input type="hidden" name="asignatura" value='.$fetch['asignatura'].'> 
 <div class="row"><div class="col-12">'.'<button type="submit"><img 
  src="'.$image_location.'"/></button>'.'</div></div>
  <div class="row"><div class="col-12">'.$name.'</div></div></form>
   </td>';
   //there is a magic - if our counter is greater then 5 we set counter to 
 zero and close tr tag
       if ($i>3){
           $i=0;
             echo '</tr>'; };
        $i++; //$i = $i + 1 - counter + 1}
          echo '</table>';
    } } ?></div></div>
```

Comment: Te podemos apoyar pero agrega lo que lleves por favor

Comment: Esta confusa tu pregunta, puedes indicar con código tu pregunta